# Proper way to initialize angular module and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to learn angular.js and have seen a few different ways to initialize the module and controller.

here is how i found to do it through debugging one site I have been using as a guide.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myController", myController);

function myController($scope) {
     //some code
}
```

and her is a way I have seen it done on a few different tutorials

```
angular.moudule('myApp', []).controller('myController', function($scope){
    //some code
}
```

I understand that this may be a personal preference but I would like to know if there is a preferred way or a cleaner way to do it. Also if there is a better way to do please mention that as well.

Comment: This is the style guide I use: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: I like the guide I will read through it

Answer (score 1):

Those two ways have more than one difference:

- having a global var
- chaining methods
- inline callback function

That gives us eight total combinations from your two examples, which makes a direct comparison of each tedious. Use whatever you find the most readable to you (and your team) and appropriate for the project (for example, will you need that `myApp` variable elsewhere in the code such as for loading components from external files, etc). If you still can't decide, there are a couple of Angular style guides online, explore them.

Answer (score 0):

I do also follow john papa's style guide.. as per that you should define controllers as

```
/* recommended */

// some.controller.js
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SomeController', SomeController);

function SomeController() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but always reusable one is better and helpful one.

> Keeping module in a  separate variable

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('FirstController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greet = 'Hi Im First Controller !';
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FirstController">
  {{ greet }}
</div>
```

> Chaining the Method

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('SecondController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.greet = 'Hi Im Chained Second Controller !';
    }]);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SecondController">
      {{ greet }}
    </div>
```